# Matching a Partial object does not work when constructing the object using an object literal when using generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, partial

When using the following construct Typescript fails to infer the correct type and match it with a partial of the same object. I assume this is not a bug and I am missing something. Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

```
class Repository<DTO extends {
    id: string
}> {
    findOne(what: Partial<DTO>) {
    }

    get(id: DTO["id"]) {
        this.findOne({ id }); // TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: DTO["id"]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial '.
        this.findOne({ id } as Partial<DTO>); // manual casting works
    }
}
```

If anybody has a better suggestion for the title please go ahead, this is almost impossible to search.

Comment: It's a design limitation of TS.  See the linked question and answer for more info